# Area selection between three curves

Tags: integration, area, curves

I would like to calculate the area on Oxy plane between the curves y=x^2, y=2, y=2x.
These curves define two areas R1 and R2, as shown below.
I know how to calculate the area but my question is which area to select R1 or R2?
Is there a rule on how to decide which area is meant if you asked to calculate the area between these curves?
[image]

Comment: I don't see any criteria for choosing between $R_1$ and $R_2$ Ask your instructor...

Comment: @JeanMarie I did ask. I was told that it is obvious :)

Comment: If the criteria is computation easiness, choose $R_2$...

Comment: While I would guess that the instructor meant $R1$, I think you should just go ahead a solve both problems. It will be useful to you, and perhaps the instructor as well. By the way, you can readily show that $R1+R2=4/3$.